# ListTemplates in DocuSign e-signature throwing error

Tags: docusignapi

I am fetching List of Templates for account, for this I am using

```
TemplatesApi templatesApi = new TemplatesApi(apiClient);
EnvelopeTemplateResults templateSummary = templatesApi.ListTemplates(AccountId);
List<EnvelopeTemplate> envelopeTemplates = templateSummary.EnvelopeTemplates;
```

With some accounts it is throwing error of null, Value can't be null, Parameter name :Value unable to read data and sometimes lack permission error.

Is there any other way to fetch templates of account? or do I need to enable any setting for this?

Comment: You said this only happen with some accounts? Are these on production or the developer env? If you log to these accounts' web app - do you see the templates?

Answer (score 0):

Some accounts will have zero templates.

So you need to test with that corner-case. In that case, the SDK should return a zero-length array (list). If it doesn't, that needs to be investigated.

Next steps: I suggest that you use the [API logger](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see **exactly** what is being returned from DocuSign for the zero templates case. Your software will then need to handle the case properly.